# TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING calls many times when some call coming

Tags: android

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    tm.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
                // phone ringing
                Log.d("ervin", incomingNumber);
                phone = incomingNumber;

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append("phone").append("&").append("com.android.phone").append("&").append(phone);
                service.writeData(sb.toString());
            }else if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE== state){ 
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append("endphone").append("&").append("com.android.phone").append("&").append(phone);
                service.writeData(sb.toString());
            }
        }
    }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE); //listener
}
```

this is my receiver code listen to the call coming and call end.
when the call is coming TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING will call many times,and my Log.d() will print many times.

my question is how can i make the TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING state just call one time when call is coming

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i just add one filter:

filter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
            registerReceiver(inCallReceiver, filter);

and I want the TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING just call one time when call is coming

Comment: It will continue to notify you of the state. It is your responsibility to handle your specific logic once.

Comment: @novak Thank you for your tips